# Single user box, do user groups matter?

Tags: chmod, chown

I have a single user box that I have setup as a home server.  I'm the only one that ever logs into it, and will be the only one to ever log into it.  I tend to `chmod 755` for most files/directories and protect files by `chown root:root` so that they cannot be accidentally deleted (i.e. photos, etc.).  To be fair, I do use `samba` so I can network the PC to the other PCs in the house.

Is there a reason for me to have user groups in this setup? Or is `chown <user>:<user>` fine and good enough?

Comment: It would be safer to run regular backups with something like `restic` or `borgbackup` (onto external storage). Then you know you have a backup and you don't have to protect files from yourself.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I do that as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your distribution, there may already exist a number of default groups that control access to various things: see the documentation of your distribution for details.

For example, on Debian/Ubuntu you might find:

- `plugdev` for access to hot-plugged devices
- `lpadmin` for printer administration
- `scanner` for scanner access
- `cdrom` for CD/DVD burner access
- `audio` for access to audio devices when logged in remotely
- `video` for access to web cameras, TV tuners and other video hardware on remote logins
- `dialout`, `uucp` and/or `dip` for serial ports, depending on exactly what you're planning to do with them (`dialout` is probably the most generic one; `uucp` if you want to use the old `cu` command or other tools from the old UUCP software package; and `dip` if you want to set up PPP-based network connections.)

In some distributions you will automatically gain a temporary membership to some or all of these groups when logged in locally, but not necessarily when using any type of remote login. These groups are an easy way to allow access to use the respective system capabilities remotely.

Comment: Thank you.  Found all the groups by using the obviously named `groups` command. *facepalm*